# Set different Font-Size for each character in a string using Blend Visual Studio WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, string, visual-studio-2010, expression-blend

[image: Just like this]I am trying to create a text-box which will have exactly 7 characters out of which first 4 might be medium sized, next 2 might be too big, and last digit might appear as power to the last two digits that were too big. This is seriously something that is troubling alot, even after working for a long while with this.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: I don't know if this works in Blend, but you can use `Run` elements inside a `TextBlock` that can be styled (including font size) indiviually. If you need a `TextBox` (i.e. something the user can edit), I think you have to switch to a `RichTextBox` which provides similar nested elements to provide the individual styling per character.

Comment: yes that worked @Onur Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something along the lines of this

**XAML**

```
<RichTextBox>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <Run FontSize="8" x:Name="SmallRun">
                1234
            </Run>
            <Run FontSize="16" x:Name="LargeRun">
                34
            </Run>
            <Run x:Name="PowerRun">
                4
            </Run>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

**C#**

```
var text = LargeRun.Text;
var firstNo = int.Parse(text.Substring(0, 1));
var secondNo = int.Parse(text.Substring(1, 1));
PowerRun.FontSize = Math.Pow(firstNo, secondNo);
```

I put it on [GitHub](https://github.com/jonstodle/SO-31875062) too.

**Edit**
I see you have edited your question. I think most of the code I posted is still relevant, but you might end doing some different styling.

**Edit 2**
Image of the code running:
[image]

**Edit 3**
You could do this

```
<Run x:Name="PowerRun" BaselineAlignment="Superscript" FontSize="8">
    4
</Run>
```

and get this
[image]

Comment: Power run didnt worked

Comment: Added an image showing the code running on my pc

Comment: code is still very fine I got it what you were tryin to show. But The last digit in power is still an issue.

Comment: You need to have BaselineAlignment="Superscript" in your Run anywasy thankyou. it worked I modified your answer.

Comment: Thanx alot for the quick help.